# using associate method in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Assume we have one to many relationship like `post` and `comment`, each post `hasMany` comments and each comment `belongsTo` one post.
The question is how we could call `associate` method? 
in Laravel document the `associate` method is called on relation method, something like:

```
$comment = new Comment(['title' => 'something']);    
$post->comments()->associate($comment);
```

but in some cases, I saw the `associate` method is called on relation attribute like:

```
$comment = new Comment(['title' => 'something']);    
$post->comments->associate($comment);
```

Are they the same? is there any difference between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think calling `associate` on a loaded relationship property works as it's either a database collection or a model (depends on the type of the relation). The method `associate` is only available on [BelongsTo](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.html#method_associate) and [MorphTo](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.html#method_associate) relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that `associate` is only applicable in one-to-one and one-to-many relationships. the usage of `associate` method on relation attribute is seen in a book called "learning laravel's eloquent". that's why I asked this question.

Comment: This must be a typo then. But go ahead and try yourself. Maybe I'm wrong here but I couldn't find anything regarding an `associate` method on models (even on older versions of Laravel) nor do I remember using it that way.